# Importing a single rxjs operator not working with react and webpack

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable for react app and webpack for bundling.

When I include a specific operator from rxjs like

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';
```

it doesn't work and throws error

```
TypeError: action$.ofType(...).mapTo is not a function.
```

But when I include complete rxjs library, it works

```
import 'rxjs';
```

When importing specific operator, my js bundle does contain mapTo code but the methods are not getting included in Observable prototype.  I am using webpack for bundling. Do we have to do anything special for importing specific operator in webpack?

**Code**:

```
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';

const PING = 'PING';
const PONG = 'PONG';

const pingEpic = action$ => {
  const obser = action$.ofType(PING);
  return obser.mapTo({ type: PONG });
}

export const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(combineEpics(pingEpic));
export const createRootEpic = (action$, store) =>
epic$.mergeMap(epic =>
  epic(action$, store)
);
```

---

**Update**:

`mapTo` method is available to `BehaviorSubject` object (`epic$.mapTo` is available) but not to `ActionsObservable` object (`action$.mapTo` is not a function).

Comment: Did you try `import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";`?

Comment: @msanford Updated question to reflect `MapTo` instead of `switchMap`.

Comment: In your `webpack.config.js`, add a [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions) array containing `["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", ".json"]`. Did that help?

Comment: Yeah but it didn't work.

Comment: Strange thing is, import complete rxjs works and it is also included in the bundled map but importing specific operator, code gets included in the js bundle but file not included in bundled map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is highly likely to be that you accidentally have two copies of RxJS. This can happen in several situations, but in your specific case it sounds highly likely to [a recently reported issue in rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2984). That particular issue was fixed started in 5.5.1 (5.5.2 is now the latest).

Make sure you have RxJS 5.5.1 or above installed--you may need to remove your node_modules and reinstall to get a newer version locally if your semver range is broad. You can also triple check by looking at node_modules/rxjs/package.json the `"version"` field, usually at the bottom

Comment: I reinstalled all packages just to remove two copies of RxJS (if any) and updated raxjs to 5.5.2. But it didn't work.

Comment: I am using` BehaviorSubject` for async addition of epics. When I import an operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';`, it is available to `BehaviorSubject` object but not to `ActionsObservable` object.

Comment: Hey @PranabGupta I see you accepted my answer, did it end up working?

Comment: Yes, it was due to two copies of RxJS because of SSR.

Comment: I'm having same issue with 6.5.4. Works fine until you pack it with webpack, yarn.lock shows only one version of rxjs. Any more hints?